# How to reuse a class method defined in one class which can be used in another class in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop

So, I'm new to Typescript, and recently started learning from documentation. I was looking at its documentation and there were no signs of reusing method from other class.
Class A file

```
 export class A{
 ... constuctor(){
 const queue = this.createQueue()
  }

 createQueue(){
  console.log("Has access to this", +this);
   }
 }
```

And there is a class B with exact same definations and uses the same method. How do I make this reusable so that, both of them call with "this"?
One solution I thought of is to create a seperate helper Class that could I use, but I'm not sure how to do that.
Any thoughts?

Comment: "*there is a class B with exact same definations*" - if it's exactly the same, don't use two separate classes in the first place?! At best use `const B = A;`

Comment: Are you new to TypeScript only or also to JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not an expert at Javascript, but i'm weeker at OOP concepts of javascript

Answer (score 0):

In this case, inheritance would probably be your best bet.  This basically means that you can extend upon another class and include all of the other one's properties/getters/setters/methods.

```
// we denote this class as abstract because it must be extended and cannot be directly initialized, i.e. new BaseFoo()
abstract class BaseFoo<T> { // `T` is the item type within the queue
    queue: T[];

    constructor() {
        this.queue = this.createQueue();
    }
    
    createQueue() {
        // can access `this`
        return [];
    }
}

class FooA extends BaseFoo<number> {
    constructor() {
        super(); // runs child class's constructor
        console.log(this.queue); // []
    }
}

class FooB extends BaseFoo<string> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this.queue); // []
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgMQHsCAeAFQD4EBvBAeloQANTGEBLDCACx3YhwC2CCAE8ADrwDubbmwB2wnggCOAVxzqAUAh0r16gFwJSAbQC6Abk3bdsAnMhRV8AlAAUASmo3du2WAA6NQ1eAF5FDgDYKBxgfgBFfRxPK18AXx8ETOjYhKTPb19feiRgBThYHHQmf0ZM3xiIVSgFc1TdDIzNFDQMQgIAQQQcAA9+OQATDGwwfCJiOVUBEBwoSips+0dnCFcCjaLdMFUJdw8LOgYnByQuNmQJpFR0AHIMOwdoHdd62y2CZA4ALIAgAczc-iCSXOlwQ5kynWsPWq-UwwzGOEm01w-WIjnkoPWm0+ThcZ0KhwQx1OKV+Og+YABQJB4MhwXUMJK8PSmjSQA)